# How to mass flash STM32 Microcontrollers through JTAG Chain with OpenOCD?

Tags: tcl, stm32, openocd, jtag, st-link

I am a beginner to OpenOCD and I am trying to flash 3 STM32 targets in a daisy chain with an ST-Link v2 debugger or OLIMEX as shown below using OpenOCD.

[image: JTAG Chain]

The code that I use works if only one Target is connected. But if I connect it to more than one Target, OpenOCD throws an error stating that init failed.

`"C:\Program Files\GNU ARM Eclipse\OpenOCD\0.10.0-201601101000-dev\bin\openocd" -f "C:\Program Files\GNU ARM Eclipse\OpenOCD\0.10.0-201601101000-dev\scripts\interface\stlink-v2.cfg" -f "C:\Program Files\GNU ARM Eclipse\OpenOCD\0.10.0-201601101000-dev\scripts\target\stm32f3x.cfg" -c init -c targets -c "halt" -c "flash  erase_sector 0 0 127" -c "reset halt" -c "flash write_image C:/Users/Buero-1/Desktop/openOCD/init.hex" -c "verify_image C:/Users/Buero-1/Desktop/openOCD/init.hex" -c "reset run" -c shutdown`

A successful result I get when this code is executed is shown below.

```html
GNU ARM Eclipse 64-bits Open On-Chip Debugger 0.10.0-dev-00287-g85cec24-dirty (2016-01-10-10:13)
Licensed under GNU GPL v2
For bug reports, read
        http://openocd.org/doc/doxygen/bugs.html
Info : auto-selecting first available session transport "hla_swd". To override use 'transport select <transport>'.
adapter speed: 1000 kHz
adapter_nsrst_delay: 100
Info : The selected transport took over low-level target control. The results might differ compared to plain JTAG/SWD
none separate
Info : Unable to match requested speed 1000 kHz, using 950 kHz
Info : Unable to match requested speed 1000 kHz, using 950 kHz

Info : clock speed 950 kHz
Info : STLINK v2 JTAG v29 API v2 SWIM v7 VID 0x0483 PID 0x3748
Info : using stlink api v2
Info : Target voltage: 3.223311
Info : stm32f3x.cpu: hardware has 6 breakpoints, 4 watchpoints
    TargetName         Type       Endian TapName            State
--  ------------------ ---------- ------ ------------------ ------------
 0* stm32f3x.cpu       hla_target little stm32f3x.cpu       halted
Info : device id = 0x20006432
Info : flash size = 256kbytes
erased sectors 0 through 127 on flash bank 0 in 0.025984s
Info : Unable to match requested speed 1000 kHz, using 950 kHz
Info : Unable to match requested speed 1000 kHz, using 950 kHz
adapter speed: 950 kHz
stm32f3x.cpu: target state: halted
target halted due to debug-request, current mode: Thread
xPSR: 0x01000000 pc: 0xfffffffe msp: 0xfffffffc
Info : Padding image section 0 with 31880 bytes
Info : Padding image section 1 with 1 bytes
stm32f3x.cpu: target state: halted
target halted due to breakpoint, current mode: Thread
xPSR: 0x61000000 pc: 0x2000003a msp: 0xfffffffc
wrote 47676 bytes from file Z:/Elektronik/GSV13/Fertigung_GSV-13iu/Init/GSV13init_Ver1_6.hex in 1.635796s (28.462 KiB/s)
stm32f3x.cpu: target state: halted
target halted due to breakpoint, current mode: Thread
xPSR: 0x61000000 pc: 0x2000002e msp: 0xfffffffc
stm32f3x.cpu: target state: halted
target halted due to breakpoint, current mode: Thread
xPSR: 0x61000000 pc: 0x2000002e msp: 0xfffffffc
verified 15795 bytes in 0.483325s (31.914 KiB/s)
Info : Unable to match requested speed 1000 kHz, using 950 kHz
Info : Unable to match requested speed 1000 kHz, using 950 kHz
adapter speed: 950 kHz
shutdown command invoked
```

But as mentioned, if I connect multiple targets in a JTAG chain, the process stops at **init** and the program ends.

The config files are target/stm32f3x.cfg, interface/ftdi/olimex-arm-usb-ocd-h.cfg and interface/stlink-v2.cfg.

Please excuse me if my question was very basic. It would be of great help if I am provided an update on how to proceed with my problem.

Thank you.

Comment: What is the full error message when things fail?

Comment: Hello Donal,
I found out how to Flash a daisy chain using OLIMEX since ST Link doesnt support JTAG chain. But I have a problem where, once flashed (and it is flashed properly), the connection fails and I am unable to flash the CPUs again. It says "flash write algorithm aborted by target".
I am trying to find out where the problem lies.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know STLink v2 does not support daisy chain.

https://community.st.com/s/question/0D50X00009XkZTdSAN/does-stlink-utility-support-multiple-devices-on-jtag-chain